# Listbox or Textbox in GridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have a gridview and based on the data type of each row, I wanna display a textbox or listbox.

How can I display a listbox or textbox based on the data type of each row of my gridview.

Obs* I'm using devexpress controls, so I'll accept both answers, for windows forms standard controls, or devexpress suite.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Do you have some code that shows what you tried?  What do you mean by _data type in each row_?

Comment: Didn't any coding yet. About data type, you can use as example the type A and the type B, because i'll define them later. In this example type A is class A, type B is class B.

Comment: Why am I getting negative votes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could likely leverage one of the built in events in the Designer (like ShowingEditor) and check the row's type by getting the row's handle from the event's args. You can then figure out what your type is here and create a new instance of Listbox or Textbox. You can read more of the documentation here:

[Dev Express ShowingEditor Event Docs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShowingEditortopic)

If you wanted to do this in code, after initializing your view, you could take your gridview and do something like this (in C#):

```
this.myGridView.ShowingEditor += (sender, args) => 
{ 
    var gridView = sender as GridView;

    if(null != gridView)
    {
        var currentRowHandle = gridView.FocusedRowHandle;
        var currentType = gridView.Rows[currentRowHandle].GetType();

        if(currentType == typeof(TypeA))
        {
             //Make a ListBox
        }

        if(currentType == typeof(TypeB))
        {
            //Make a TextBox
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously there's more code to be written here, but I think this will get you started.

Comment: Omg, this community is crazy, I was reading an answer you posted some while ago, and then you showed in my question with the proper answer, unbelievable.

Thanks for the help. Dont see why my question deserves negatives votes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear to me **at all**, but maybe you have a custom Row Type and are trying to do something like this

```
public class ListBoxRow : Row {}
public class TextBoxRow : Row {}

List<Row> rows = new List<Row>(){new ListBoxRow(), new TextBoxRow()}

foreach (Row r in rows)
{
    If (r is ListBoxRow) {//Create ListBox }
    If (r is TextBoxRow ) {//Create TextBox }
}
```

Comment: It's something like that, I'll try later this code(at job right now), and post the results, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a style, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa) an article with some examples, I hope you enjoy it.